# Auth.RegistrationHandler Picking termed member

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, single-sign-on

We are implementing inbound SSO from microsoft Azure AD, and the implementation is success. OUr objective is to make internal & external users to SSO to our system. SO as a testing we created an salesforce User(SFDC) and able to access the SSO url and it visits teh Active directory for authentication and then successfully redirects to comunity portal or SFDC portal.
and then we termed the member. Now we created an external user with same emailAddress. and again we access teh SSO url, in this case the salesforce picks the termed member not the community member. and it goes to updateUser method when we check the userID, it is termed member ID.

we are tying to understand why SF picks the termed member instead of active member with mapped emailAddress?
Please help
Thanks

Comment: ...because that's how auto-generated out of the box handler works. You'll need to modify it.

Comment: Hi
The fix is we need to revoke the third party access from user record . First time it goes to create user method and then it maps the reference and next time it is accessed it will go to update user method of handler . 
So In this case I went to termed member and revoked the third party access mapped. Now again visit the Sso url and now it will pick the next user I

Thanks